# Create JavaScript Array of Random Ints

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In Python, if I want a random array of integers up to a certain size, I do:

```
random_array = numpy.random.randint(20, size=10)
```

In Javascript, I can not figure out a good one-line way to do this.  I tried using UnderscoreJS:

```
random_array = _.sample(_.range(20), 10);
```

I also tried using Javascript 1.7 array comprehensions plus UnderscoreJS:

```
random_array = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) for (x of _.range(10))];
```

The first one creates only unique values, the second way does not seem to work at all.  Any ideas?  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I tried the `_.sample` version and it works fine. http://jsbin.com/pasif/1/edit

Comment: I think `numpy.random.randint` creates a set of numbers where each of them is uniformly choosen from `[0,n)`, is that correct? If so, your JS approach is incorrect anyways: It will create a fixed list of 20 values and you randomly choose 10 of them.

Comment: Yea, I do not want each value to be unique - that is the reason why _.sample() does not work for this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [`_.times`](http://underscorejs.org/#times) and [`_.random`](http://underscorejs.org/#random) would be useful:

```
var random_array = _.times(10, _.random.bind(_, 0, 19));
```

You could also create a tiny helper function around `_.random`:

```
function randomIntFactory(max) {
    // _.random's max value is *inclusive* (unlike the Python version)
    // so we subtract one
    return _.random.bind(_, 0, max - 1);
}

var random_array = _.times(10, randomIntFactory(20));
```

---

Note: Instead of native `.bind` you can also use underscore's [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind).

Answer (score 2):

If you want just a (fairly long) javascript one-liner without underscore/other libraries:

```
var random_array = function (){var a=[]; for(var i=0;i<10;i++){a[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*20);};return a;}();
```

This is in answer to "any ideas?"
I'm not sure if it's an answer to "what is the best way?"